# Grep the most recent value of a particular column from a CSV file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

```
"cola","colb","colc","cold","cole","colf"
"a","b","c","d","e","f"
"a1","b1","c1","d1","e1","f1"
"a2","b2","c2","d2","e2","f2"
```

Assuming this is the CSV file, I want to `grep` the value `"e"` from the column `"cole"` and store it into a shell variable. And then use the shell variable as a part of a `wget` command.

How would I do this?

Comment: Is first line (cola colb colc cold cole colf) part of your csv file?

Comment: First line is the column name and yeah a part of the csv file

Comment: Changed it to the most recent value and above is the representation in Excel, it indeed is a csv file.

Comment: @Ed Morton: I could have 'cat', but the data is not meant to be made public, the question is forward enough. I have a CSV, extract the recent (first value since it was sorted desc, put the 5th column in a shell variable and use it in wget). Down-vote was uncalled for, I have been looking for this for a day now, otherwise I don't post without extensive searching. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It makes sense now. Thanks for the explanation : "a","b","c","d","e","f" -> This is the format

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO isn't a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

```
set -f         # disable globbing
variable="$(awk 'NR==2 {print $5}' file)"
set +f
```

Comment: This is using printing lines between 7th and 8th column, the separator seems to be off. And if I delete the unwanted columns, print$1/$2... so on returns a null value on the variable.

Comment: Here is the output
$ set -f
$ variable="$(awk 'NR==2 {print $5}' a.csv)"
$ set +f
$ echo $variable

$ variable="$(awk 'NR==2 {print $4}' a.csv)"
$ echo $variable

$ variable="$(awk 'NR==2 {print $3}' a.csv)"
$ echo $variable

$ variable="$(awk 'NR==2 {print $1}' a.csv)"
$ echo $variable

It is just printing blanks

Answer (score 1):

Awk is well suited to this. If you know the column number you can simply do:

```
$ awk 'NR==2{print $5}' file.csv 
e
```

This will print the fifth field on the second line. If you want to use the column name then:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)c[$i]=i}NR==2{print $c[col]}' col="cole" file.csv
e
```

Just set `col="<name of column to use>"`.

You can use command substitution to store the value in variable:

```
$ val="$(awk 'NR==2{print $5}' file.csv)"
$ wget --what-ever-option "$val"
```

Or just use it in place:

```
$ wget --what-ever-option "$(awk 'NR==2{print $5}' file.csv)"
```